# Why onNext has no effect

Tags: java, java-8, observable, rx-java2

As shown below, I am learning how to use rxjava. I want to know how to use map operator to display how many Person objects in each list.
the problem is, when i run the code onNext from the observable is never called.

Note: the person class posted below contains Optional attributes.

please let me how to display how many Person objects in the each list using map operator.

thanks in advance

**code**:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<List<Person>> observables = Observable.create(e-> {
        for(List<Person> p : Main.getPersons()) {
            e.onNext(p);
        }
        e.onComplete();
    });
     observables
    .map(p->p.size())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new Observer() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("onNextFromObserver: " + arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

private static <T> Observable<T> toObservable(T s) {
    return Observable.just(s);
}
private static List<List<Person>> getPersons() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Sanna1", 59, "EGY"), new Person(null, 59, "EGY"), new Person("Sanna3", 59, null)),
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Mohamed1", 59, "EGY"), new Person(null, 59, "EGY")),
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Ahmed1", 44, "QTR"), new Person("Ahmed2", 44, "QTR"), new Person(null, null, "QTR")),
                    Arrays.asList(new Person("Fatma", 29, "KSA")),
                    Arrays.asList(new Person("Lobna", 24, "EGY")));
}
}
```

**Person**

```
public class Person {
private String name = null;
private String address = null;
private int age;

private Optional<String> optName= null;
private Optional<Integer> optAge= null;
private Optional<String> optAddress = null;

public Person(String name, Integer age, String address) {
    this.optName = Optional.ofNullable(name);
    this.optAge = Optional.ofNullable(age);
    this.optAddress = Optional.ofNullable(address);
}

public Optional<String> getName() {
    return optName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.optName = Optional.ofNullable(name);
}

public Optional<String> getAddress() {
    return this.optAddress;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.optAddress = Optional.ofNullable(address);
}

public Optional<Integer> getAge() {
    return this.optAge;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.optAge = Optional.ofNullable(age);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your `onNext` doesn't get executed has to do with the fact that `Schedulers.io()` uses daemon threads. This means that they do not keep the JVM running if no other threads are active.

Simply put since your `main` function ends and the only running code is the IO scheduler which will call `onNext` in the future. The JVM quits before that can actually happen since no non-daemon threads are active. Use `blockingSubscribe` to block the main thread until the observable has finished and you will see the output you're expecting.